# Is there any trick to avoid the `typename` keyword inside a template class?

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, dependent-type

I am trying to achieve something like the following:

```cpp
template <typename T>
class MyClass {
    struct nested {
        using OtherT = // Some type derived from T
    };

protected:
    // Any way to avoid `typename` here?
    typename nested::OtherT member;
};
```

Is there any way to use types nested in a struct / namespace / other, that are computed from the template type `T`, without using needing the `typename` keyword?
I am open to declaring `nested` in any other way, its purpose is only to hold types.

**Edit**: the reason I am trying to do this is that I will have a whole collection of types derived from `T` already visible inside of `MyClass`, and then closely related variants of those same types inside of `nested`. I am hoping to use `nested` to tell them apart in a clear and concise way.
This situation will appear in many places over the codebase, so I was hoping to avoid to see `typename` everywhere these types are mentioned.

Comment: No. No way yet.

Comment: What's the *problem* with having to type out "typename"? It's only 8 characters.

Comment: Depends what exactly you mean, you can use a type alias or a template type alias. `using OtherT = typename nested::OtherT;` then `OtherT member;`. Only really usefull if the reason you want it is because you need to use `OtherT` many times in your class definition.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/): what do you want to achieve and why do you do it this way?

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I edited the question with additional context.

Comment: Note that C++20 significantly reduces the number of places that `typename` is required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't put them in a type like that. If you need to tell them apart, give them a more descriptive name. Even if your preferred mechanism worked, you'd have to prefix the names with `nested::` anyway. So just make that part of the name and get it over with:

```
template <typename T>
class MyClass {
    using nested_OtherT = // Some type derived from T

protected:
    nested_OtherT member;
};
```